# Probabilities of survival vs. probabilities of being sampled

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a (very large, or even infinite) population of biological organisms, which are of one of two types, $A$ or $B$. At birth, these types have relative frequencies of $p$ and $q$, respectively. A sample of size $n$ of this set of individuals is taken, representing those who make it into adulthood.

I'm told that type $A$ individuals have a probability of $s_1$ of surviving into adulthood, while type $B$ have a probability of $s_2$ (these probabilities don't necessarily add up to 1).

What I want to know is the probability of obtaining a sample with $k$ $A$ individuals. I believe that if I knew the probability of sampling an $A$ individual vs. the probability of sampling a $B$ individual (call them $t_1$ and $t_2$, with $t_1+t_2=1$), that would be as easy as using a binomial distribution, the answer to my question being: $P$($k$ $A$ individuals) $= \binom{n}{k} {t_1}^k {t_2}^{(n-k)}$

The thing is I don't know those probabilities ($t_1$ and $t_2$), nor do I know how to obtain them from the survival ones ($s_1$ and $s_2$) and the relative frequencies. Any help?

Comment: Why not have $t_1=\dfrac{ps_1}{ps_1+qs_2}$ and $t_2=\dfrac{qs_2}{ps_1+qs_2}$ ?

Comment: I don't know... would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intuitive way to think of this is to consider that in a deterministic cohort of $n_0$ organisms at birth, the expected number of organisms of type $A$ would be $n_0 p$, and the expected number of organisms of type $B$ would be $n_0 q$, with $p + q = 1$.  Then the number of organisms of each type that survive into adulthood are $n_0 p s_1$ and $n_0 q s_2$, for $A$ and $B$, respectively.  Their sum represents the total cohort surviving into adulthood, and the proportion of each type is therefore $$t_1 = \frac{n_0 p s_1}{n_0 p s_1 + n_0 q s_2} = \frac{p s_1}{p s_1 + q s_2}, \quad t_2 = \frac{n_0 q s_2}{n_0 p s_1 + n_0 q s_2} = \frac{q s_2}{p s_1 + q s_2}.$$  For a sufficiently large cohort at birth (such that the relevant counts are not less than 1), we see that the above represent probabilities of sampling organisms of each type at adulthood.

Answer (score 0):

$t_1, t_2$ are the *expected frequencies* of the adult populations with initial frequency $p, q$ (where $p+q=1$), and survival *rates* $s_1, s_2$.

So if you tag and track a sample of $mp$ type $A$ and $mq$ type $B$ infants (total $m$), what would the *expected* surviving adult populations be?

From that obtain the required *frequencies*.